# Handling empty data in Repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have tried numerous tutorials about trying to display a label to the user when there is no data to be shown from a repeater. Please! can someone tell me if they know why the label will not show? Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Notifications" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Notifications_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <!-- directs us back to the previous page -->
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkReturn" runat="server" >
            <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:black; font-size: xx-large !important;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
        </asp:LinkButton>
        <h1>Notifications</h1>
        <hr />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="repeater-border">
        <b><u>Problem Number:</u></b>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Problem_Id")%><br />
        <b><u>Tenant Name:</u></b>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Tenant_FullName")%><br />
        <b><u>Property Address:</u></b>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Property_Address")%><br />
        <b><u>Message:</u></b>&nbsp;<%# Eval("Message")%><br />
        <!-- link that allows landlords to delete the tenant from that property -->
        <asp:HyperLink ID="DeleteLink" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Problem_Id","DeleteProblem.aspx?id={0}") %>' runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    <!-- Label used for showing Error Message -->
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" Text="No Data To Display" runat="server" Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Behind Code:

```
string checkLandlord = String.Empty;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkLandlord += Session["LandlordLogin"];

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Creating a connection to my database using the connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rent-dbConnectionString1"].ToString();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        //preparing a query which will select all properties matching the landlord that is logged in at that moment
        comm.CommandText = "select prob.Message, prop.Property_Address, t.Tenant_FullName, t.Tenant_Email from Properties prop join Tenants t on prop.Property_Id = t.Property_Id  join Problems prob on prop.Property_Id = prob.Property_Id and prob.Tenant_Id = t.Tenant_Id join Landlords l on prop.Landlord_Id = l.Landlord_Id where l.Landlord_Email ='" + checkLandlord + "'";
        comm.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                Notifications.DataSource = reader;
                Notifications.DataBind();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }
}
protected void Notifications_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (Notifications.Items.Count < 1)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblFooter = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEmptyData");
            lblFooter.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for what "Items" that the line "if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)" is triggered?

Comment: Are you asking how to do `if (reader.HasRows) { /*...*/} else {lblEmptyData.Visible = true}`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have tried this however it will not recognise my lable and an error says'The name "lblEmptyData" does not exist in the current context'?? Can you help me with this problem.

Comment: Maybe VS has got confused over what is on the page. I suggest that you delete the label from the page, save the page, then make a new label with a slightly different name. It should then work in the code-behind.

Comment: Why are you putting the label within the Repeater? The repeater's job is to loop over an array of data and display some repeated content for each item. It's not to display messages when there's no data, so don't nest your empty data label within it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Repeater.Items.Count == 0` to show Label when empty inside footer and there is no need of code-behind as like this:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" runat="server" 
        Visible='<%# Notifications.Items.Count == 0 %>' Text="No Data To Display" />
</FooterTemplate>
```